# Is the criticism of Peter, in Acts 11 an extrapolation of Deuteronomy 7: 1-4?

Tags: law, moses

Is the criticism on the part of the "Circumcision" of Peter's visit with Cornelius in Acts 11 an extrapolation of Deuteronomy 7:1-4?

Comment: probably.  However, it was by Peter's time more cultural than Scriptural.

Comment: Not particularly; the pagans spoken of in the Torah were polytheistic, whereas Cornelius, by contrast, was a [God-fearer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God-fearer). One could say that the war in question differs, because the ancient Jews exterminated pagans physically, whereas Christianity exterminated paganism spiritually, by converting the [Greek-Roman world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Roman_world) to its faith.